# Position HTML next to cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to position a fragment of html to appear next to where the cursor is, specifically on click. So far I have a div which will position itself next to the cursor on click.

```
 shape.on('click', function(event){ 
   if (event.which == 1) {
          $("#message").css({
                top: event.pageY + 5,
                left: event.pageX + 5
            }).show();
   }
});
```

**But rather what I am after is to not 'show' any existing div, but insert new code 'on the fly' to where the cursor is.**

Thank you

Comment: so you would like to use `$("#message").html("html text that you want")`? or `.text()`

Comment: Actually yes, that will do. I was over complicating that. Thanks Jake.

Comment: yep, I'll post as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.html()` to insert the text into the div that appears next to your cursor.

Example: `$("#message").html("html text that you want");`

If you want to continue to add text to message then use `.append()`, otherwise `.html()` will overwrite the contents of `#message` each time.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to append ([append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)) or insert ([html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)) the code you want on that div:

```
$('#message').html('Hello world!');
```

Full code:

```
 shape.on('click', function(event){ 
   if (event.which == 1) {
          $("#message").css({
                top: event.pageY + 5,
                left: event.pageX + 5
            }).show();

          $('#message').html('Hello world!');
   }
});
```

Living demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zEsF5/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can add new elements easily if you do:

```
shape.on('click', function(event){ 
  if (event.which == 1) {
    $("<div>The <strong><em>HTML</em> code</strong> you want<br/>can go here<div>").css({
           top: event.pageY + 5,
           left: event.pageX + 5,
           position: 'absolute'
    }).appendTo(shape).show();
  }
});
```

There is a working [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uyjBP/)